# Class Cast Exception, inside Adapter from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, interface

I am getting a `java.lang.ClassCastException` when trying to use an `Interface` and an `AsyncTask` from inside my adapter. I don't know if this is 'allowed', but I can't see why it wouldn't be as long as everything is kept in context.

The code starts in my `Fragment` when I try and set my `GridView` with a custom `Adapter`.

```
mSceneGridAdapter = new SceneGridAdapter(getActivity(), mScenesList);
```

Which leads to my SceneGridAdapter class being called

```
public class SceneGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements HandleProductThumbnail {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Scene> mSceneList = null;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Drawable mThumbnail;

    public SceneGridAdapter() {}

    public SceneGridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Scene> sceneList) {
        super();

        mContext = context;
        if (mSceneList != null) {
            clearData();
        } else {
            mSceneList = sceneList;
        }

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.scene_cell, null);
        }

        ImageView sceneView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sceneImage);

        Scene scene = mSceneList.get(position);
        String specifier = scene.getSpecifier() + "/" + scene.getName();
        LoadScenes scenes = new LoadScenes(mContext, specifier);
        scenes.execute();
        sceneView.setBackground(mThumbnail);

        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mSceneList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mSceneList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void clearData() {
        mSceneList.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleProductThumbnail(Drawable thumb) {
        mThumbnail = thumb;
    }
}
```

Which implements my `Interface` HandleProductThumbnails

```
public interface HandleProductThumbnail {
        void handleProductThumbnail(Drawable thumb);
}
```

and then calls my `AsyncTask` loader class called LoadScenes, which loads the thumbnails and returns them to the adapter.

```
public class LoadScenes extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Drawable> {
    private static final String LOADING = "Loading...";
    private static final String PNG = "_ORIGINAL.PNG";

    private Context mContext;
    private HandleProductThumbnail mHandleThumbnail = null;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private String mSpecifier;

    public LoadScenes () {}

    public LoadScenes (Context context, String specifier) {
        mContext = context;
        mSpecifier = specifier;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(LOADING);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    public Drawable doInBackground(Void... v) {
        Drawable productThumbnail = getDrawable(mSpecifier);
        return productThumbnail;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(Drawable productThumbnail) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        mHandleThumbnail = (HandleProductThumbnail) mContext;
        mHandleThumbnail.handleProductThumbnail(productThumbnail);
    }

    public Drawable getDrawable(String specifier) {
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        Drawable productThumbnail = null;
        specifier = specifier.replace("\\", "/") + PNG;
        try {
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mContext.getAssets().open(specifier));
            if (bmp != null) {
                int width = 300;
                int height = 240;
                bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, true);
                productThumbnail = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bmp);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return productThumbnail;
    }
}
```

and finally my log

```
09-30 10:34:35.725: E/AndroidRuntime(22442): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.xxx.visualizer.VisualizerActivity cannot be cast to com.example.xxx.interfaces.HandleProductThumbnail
09-30 10:34:35.725: E/AndroidRuntime(22442):    at com.example.xxx.visualizer.LoadScenes.onPostExecute(LoadScenes.java:46)
```

The `Fragment` is attached to an `Activity` called VisualizerActivity, and all the context being passed comes from that `Activity`. While this problem is somewhat layered, the code is fairly boilerplate. I was wondering if I am just doing something that isn't allowed? From my understanding of `Context` this should work. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong, why, and if it can be fixed. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your activity is not implementing the `HandleProductThumbnail`, but your custom adapter. In your case, instead of casting, I would rather add a method to the `AsyncTask` subclass:

```
   public void setHandleProductThumbnail(HandleProductThumbnail listener) {
           mHandleThumbnail = listener;
   }
```

and inside `OnPostExecute`

```
 public void onPostExecute(Drawable productThumbnail) {
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    if (mHandleThumbnail != null)
       mHandleThumbnail.handleProductThumbnail(productThumbnail);
}
```

Comment: That's correct, my Activity is not implementing my Interface. My Adapter is. My Adapter does this before it sets my GridView. If I return the Drawable to my Activity, how would I then pass that back to my Adapter? Do you see the problem?

Comment: you are not returning the drawable back to the activity but to adapter. In particular you are returning the result to the class the implements that interface

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here :

```
mHandleThumbnail = (HandleProductThumbnail) mContext;
```

You're casting `mContext` to `HandleProductThumbnail` whereas `mContext` is a `Context`, hence not implementing your custom interface. If you need a reference to the `HandleProductThumbnail`, pass it as a constructor argument.

Last note : if you're trying to load thumbnails on every list item, I would suggest the use of [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), which would make all this much simpler for you.

Comment: this makes sense to me, thank you for the Picasso suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly visible that it would create an class cast exception,
because mContext is your activity`s object which is not implementing the "HandleProductThumbnail" interface.

Though you rectify your code by right casting, yet it will produce error due to below lines of code in your adapter

```
    LoadScenes scenes = new LoadScenes(mContext, specifier);
    scenes.execute();
    sceneView.setBackground(mThumbnail);
```

Because second line is an async call and mThumbnail would be null.You may apply another approach for rendering images from URL at run time.